# Update timestamps in MySQL Database after changing server's timezone

Tags: php, mysql, sql, datetime, timestamp

Now I have wrong timezone set on my server, so all the records in my MySQL database have timestamps different from the real by 4 hours. How do I update all the timestamps to match the real time?

For example, I have timestamp like `2014-06-28 20:34:29`. I need it to become `2014-06-29 00:34:29`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `..SET datecol=datecol+INTERVAL 4 HOUR` Or you might need to change the timezone so its not clear.Do you want do dispaly them correctly or to UPDATE the table?

Comment: Don't update your data. Set the timezone to the right value, because **"MySQL converts TIMESTAMP values from the current time zone to UTC for storage, and back from UTC to the current time zone for retrieval."** (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html)

Comment: @VMai thank you, I'll try what you suggested

Answer (score 3):

assuming your date field is named created_at

`update <table> SET created_at = DATE_ADD(created_at,INTERVAL 4 HOUR)`